# What MAC format is this: 1:0:5e:0:0:fb?

Tags: macos, networking, network-programming, arp

I am using the `arp -a` command on MacOS, and I'm getting weird results in a MAC format I haven't seen before.
Example output:

```
arp -a
? (192.168.1.1) at 0:22:7:4a:21:d5 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (224.0.0.251) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (239.255.255.250) at 1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
```

I want to use the MAC addresses, but I can't parse them due to the weird format... What format is this, and how can I parse this to normal `FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF` format instead of `F:F:F:F:F:F`?

Comment: There is no actual standard for MAC address notation. Some devices will give you `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`, some `xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx`, some `xxxx:xxxx:xxxx`, some `xxxx-xxxx-xxxx`, etc. You can easily parse what you get by the colon, make it two digits, and put it back together. [so] is not a code writing service, and you do not even mention a programming language or show any of your code.

Comment: It's just leaving off leading zeroes on each of the numbers, e.g. "0" instead of "00", "1" instead of "01", etc.

Answer (score 1):

I make a simple Go function to solve the leaving off leading zeroes problem:

```
// FixMacOSMACNotation fixes the notation of MAC address on macOS.
// For instance: 1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa becomes 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa
func FixMacOSMACNotation(s string) string {
    var newString string
    split := strings.Split(s, ":")
    for i, s := range split {
        if i != 0 {
            newString += ":"
        }
        if len(s) == 1 {
            newString += "0" + s
        } else {
            newString += s
        }
    }
    return newString
}
```

Which can then be used in net.ParseMAC successfully.